# how to transfer data in multiple test case in Soap UI (open source)

Tags: soapui

[image]

In Log In request two tags (Email and Password) are present.

I want to use this request Email value in another Test Case (Email Validation) test step.

please give solution.

Comment: Are you running the entire test suite or just the individual test cases?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can'd do it via the GUI.  However, you can set property files for another case via a groovy script with something like

```
tCase = prj.testSuites['TestSuiteName'].testCases['TestCaseName']
tCase.setPropertyValue( "MyProp", someValue )
```

For some reason you cant perform it as a single line in my expirience.

http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html#1-1-Get-and-Set-properties